# Mock async Get method with MOQ

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, moq

How do I get rid of this error message:

```
Error   5   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TGB.Business.DTO.SchoolyearDTO>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TGB.Business.DTO.SchoolyearDTO>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I thought my Task.FromResult would fix that but no...

```
mockService.Setup<IEnumerable<SchoolyearDTO>>(c => c.GetSchoolyears()).Returns(
                    Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Empty<SchoolyearDTO>()));

public async Task<IEnumerable<SchoolyearDTO>> GetSchoolyearsAsync()
{
    var schoolyears = await ...
}
```

Comment: You are returning a task to something that doesn't accept one. You need to change either the mock, or the method.

Comment: Not accept one? But my GetSchoolyears awaits a Task?

Comment: See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetSchoolyearsAsync` is an async method, so it returns a `Task<IEnumerable<SchoolyearDTO>>` and not just a `IEnumerable<SchoolyearDTO>`. You need to specify that in the type parameters for `SetupGet`

```
mockService.SetupGet<Task<IEnumerable<SchoolyearDTO>>>(c => c.GetSchoolyears()).
    Returns(Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Empty<SchoolyearDTO>()));
```

Comment: Now I get the error: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: c => c.GetSchoolyearsAsync() Since when do I have to make my  methods virtual with MOQ ?

Comment: @Elisa are you sure GetSchoolyearsAsync and GetSchoolyears are the same method?

Comment: I did a rename... yes only the xxxAsync exists!

Comment: Ok the reason why I have to use virtual is because MOQ can`t mock non-virtual members EXCEPT interface members. Thats the first time I use no interfaces lol... therefore I stepped into that...